# How do I replace Persian Unicode characters with what is shown?

Tags: java, unicode, farsi

I'm working on a project which was Arabic before but I'm trying to add Persian characters (like گ چ پ ژ ) to it.

So I Imported Persian Characters to it but instead of showing new Characters in their appropriate form like ـگـ in باشگاه (U+FB95) it shows the isolated form like گ in باش گ اه (U+06AF).

note: There is not any spaces between ش and گ  and ا in that word, it's only there to show how it's shown in the project.

Some other Examples:

تای ی د -> تایید

بازی ک نان -> بازیکنان

So is there any way to replace these characters with their appropriate form?

Comment: What type of project? What does this have to do with programming?

Comment: Oh! I didn't explain! I wanted to find a way to do it in java. It is a personal project.

Comment: Please share the code

Comment: It is a big pile of Code! How should I share it here?

Comment: The issue is a rendering/font issue. Unicode Arabic-script text should not use presentation form characters like U+FB95 but should use characters from the U+06xx block, like U+06AF. But then it is up to a rendering engine and font to support those characters, including displaying the appropriate connecting forms.

> It is a big pile of Code! How should I share it here?

Provide details about how the text is being displayed — what UI framework / library / APIs you're using.